# Math puzzle involving pattern

Tags: pattern

This puzzle has been bugging me for quite a few days now. I came across this puzzle in an online website.

```
2, 4, 1 = 4
3, 1, 6 = 8
7, 2, 4 = 7
1, 0, 8 = ?
```

Can someone please give a hint. Thanks!

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: Downvotes are probably due to attribution issues.  This puzzle may be on topic, but since you clearly stated that you found it online, we require a bit more detail about the source.

Comment: There's a banner along the top of your question with information about how to fix your question.

Comment: oh, ok. it is from an app called Math Riddles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Hint

> The pattern involves 4 operations: addition, concatenation, swapping and one more.

### Answer

The answer is

> $9$

because

> $\DeclareMathOperator{\swap}{swap}\DeclareMathOperator{\concat}{concat}$
>  For numbers $a, b, c = d$, we notice that   $$\sqrt{a + \concat(\swap(b, c))} = \sqrt{a + \concat(c,b)} = \sqrt{a + 10c + b} = d$$
>
>  For the given case, $$\sqrt{1 + \concat(\swap(0, 8))} = \sqrt{1 + \concat(8, 0)} = \sqrt{1 + 80} = \sqrt{81} = 9$$
>
>  This pattern is consistent with the listed numbers: \begin{align} \sqrt{2 + \concat(\swap(4, 1))} = \sqrt{2 + \concat(1, 4)} = \sqrt{2 + 14} &= \sqrt{16} = 4\\ \sqrt{3 + \concat(\swap(1, 6))} = \sqrt{3 + \concat(6, 1)} = \sqrt{3 + 61} &= \sqrt{64} = 8\\ \sqrt{7 + \concat(\swap(2, 4))} = \sqrt{7 + \concat(4, 2)} = \sqrt{7 + 42} &= \sqrt{49} = 7\\ \end{align}

Comment: Please do not answer questions which are off-topic per our [attribution policy](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7259/proper-attribution-for-non-original-puzzles-a-guide); that policy is in place to prevent cheating and plagiarism.

Comment: @bobble As a new user on this site, I wasn’t aware. Thanks for the heads up, will keep that in mind for the future.

Comment: No problem! Feel free to drop into [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14524/the-sphinxs-lair) for a more informal environment - the regulars there can talk you through how the site works if you have more questions about rules/history.